# Rails: confirm_X_url generates http and not https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I'm following along on https://coderwall.com/p/u56rra/ruby-on-rails-user-signup-email-confirmation-tutorial.  In that article, the author creates **registration_confirmation.text.erb**:

```
Hi <%= @user.name %>,

Thanks for registering! To confirm your registration click the URL below.

<%= confirm_email_user_url(@user.confirm_token) %>
```

The author does not explain how **confirm_email_user_url** is created.  I attempted to trace through the metaprogramming code and I believe it is **url_for** in source module ...lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb that eventually creates the output string.

My **registration_confirmation.text.erb** is

```
<%# See https://coderwall.com/p/u56rra/ruby-on-rails-user-signup-email-confirmation-tutorial %>

Hi <%= @email_address.email_address %>,

Thanks for registering! To confirm your registration click the URL below.

<%
  confirmation_url =
    confirm_email_email_address_url(
      @email_address.confirm_token
    )
  regex=/\A(http:\/\/)/
  confirmation_url.gsub!(regex, 'https://')
%>
<%= confirmation_url %>
```

If I don't convert the output string from http to https then I get the following error:

> Not Found The requested URL
>   /email_addresses/v8HJgSaGGysoxIC-ghX8lw/confirm_email was not found on
>   this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.myWebsite.com Port
>   80
>   If I coerce the strong to by https://... instead of http://... then all is well and the url is routed correctly to Rails.

### Questions

1. How do I tell confirm_X_url (i.e. confirm_email_user_url) to
   generate https instead of http.
2. This may not be a Rails question;
   Where in the stack do I tell Apache, Rails, something else(?) to take
   http and automagically convert it to https?  I followed the steps in
   https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61009/how-to-enable-use-of-htaccess-in-apache-on-ubuntu
   but it does not seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Do `rake routes` to see all possible routes and there you can also see the name of the routes. That name is then used to build the methods `<route-name>_path` or `<route-name>_url`.

Instead of using `_url` if you use the relative `_path` it will start from the current url (including the `https`). But this will not work when building mails.

Force the application to always use ssl in production mode by setting the flag `config.force_ssl = true` in `config/environments/production.rb`.

Also, when doing this in a mailer, you might have to set the following:

```
# production.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  host: 'yourdomain.com',
  protocol: 'https'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
confirm_email_user_url(:protocol => 'https')
```

or put this helper into app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
def default_url_options(options={})
 { :secure => true }
end
```

And that would resolve the link issue and get you running right away, but it isn't the right thing to do. You can use some .htaccess directives like these:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

or, which is what I would do, is sign-up for something like cloudflare where you get a bunch of protection for your site and it will force redirects if you ask it to.

here's a link to that info:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-